Action of a group on a graph has a point moved freely
On p. 35 of Meier's Groups, Graphs and Trees the following claim is made:

Let a group $G$ act on a connected graph $\Gamma$ with fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}$. Assume that if $g \cdot \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}$ then $g = e \in G$.
Then there is a point $x \in \mathcal{F}$ that is moved freely under the action of $G$.

I can't understand why the claim should be true. It is only made in passing and not elaborated on, so it's very possible that it's actually trivial and I'm just reading it wrong or missing something obvious.
I've tried assuming every point of $\Gamma$ has a nontrivial stabiliser and going from there, but this is complicated by how graphs are treated here with the edges identified with $[0, 1]$, hence the set $\Gamma$ is uncountable, and this seems fruitless. I think this way of defining graphs is necessary for the claim to be true.
For reference, Meier defines a fundamental domain of an action of a group $G$ on a graph $\Gamma$ to be a subset $\mathcal{F} \subset \Gamma$ such that (p. 31):


$\mathcal{F}$ is closed;
the set $\{g \cdot \mathcal{F} : g \in G\}$ covers $\Gamma$; and
no subset of $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies properties (1) and (2).


Could anyone elaborate on how to prove this, or whether I'm reading it incorrectly?
Edit: After some thought, it seems intuitively that for distinct $g, h \in G$, we should have $$(g \cdot \mathcal{F}) \cap (h \cdot \mathcal{F}) = \partial \left( g \cdot \mathcal{F} \right) \cap \partial \left( h \cdot \mathcal{F} \right);$$ that is, distinct images of $\mathcal{F}$ under the action of $G$ intersect only at their boundaries (or they are disjoint). From this assumption, the claim above seems obvious I think. But I don't know how to prove this.

The result is not dependent on the definition. Moreover, you shouldn't think that the edge set is uncountable - it is a set $E\Gamma = {e_i}_{i\in I}$ of line segments $e_i$. The segments $e_i$ are uncountable, but the set $E\Gamma$ itself can be finite, countable, or whatever. This view simply reflects how you draw a graph. Serre gives another, less immediately intuitive view in his book Trees, where edges defined in terms of pairs of maps.

@user1729 I understand that the edge set is not necessarily uncountable. But as a gluing of points and copies of $[0, 1]$, isn't $\Gamma$ necessarily uncountable as a set? If it is, this seems to pose a problem for the approach I mentioned. Also, it seems that if the point $x \in \Gamma$ can only be a vertex or edge, the claim isn't true anymore - that is, we need to view $\Gamma$ this way, we can't just consider vertices and edges. The fundamental domain will generally contain half-edges anyway.

No, in Meier's book $\Gamma$ is countable. If a single point on an edge is fixed, then so is every other point on the edge. This is because the group acts on the set $E\Gamma$, mapping $e_i\mapsto e_j$. Just ignore the internal structure of the $e_i$ and treat them as letters. It is a bit like how can construct real numbers as sets of rational numbers via Dedekins cuts - formally, $\pi$ is really a set of rational numbers, but you don't ever view it like this! You just treat it as a letter, $\pi$.

I'm sorry, I still don't understand. What about $S_3$ acting on $K_3$ by permutation of the vertices? The transposition $(12)$ fixes a single point on the edge with ends $1$ and $2$ (the midpoint) but no others. I also don't see how we can ignore the internal structure of the $e_i$, since again, a fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}$ will in general contain half-edges, which I don't know how to make sense of otherwise.

Think informally rather than precisely - I think of half-edges as "dangling", without an end-point (and drawn with a bracket at the end, "--)"). In your $S_3$ example, your fundamental domain is two vertices connected by an edge, and the transposition $(12)$ fixes vertex in the domain but not the other.

Okay, I think I must be misunderstanding things. Meier says (p. 35) that a fundamental domain for $S_n \curvearrowright K_n$ is a single half-edge. By (3) in the definition, this seems to suggest that a fundamental domain for this $S_3$ example can't be 2 vertices and the edge between them, so I must be getting confused somewhere. Also, I don't understand how $(12)$ fixes either of the vertices $1$ or $2$. I think I must be getting really mixed up somewhere. Thank you for helping though!

Sorry, my mistake - I was thinking of the graph with 4 vertices and 3 edges. However, the same issue holds - $(12)$ fixes a vertex of $K_3$, but it moves all the esges. In particular, the half-edge is moved outside of the fundamental domain.
